# Read value of a key from files and output a random amount into a file?

Tags: python, arrays, json, parsing

I have a dozen of files with the following structure:

```
{"reviewerID": "A4IL0CLL27Q33", "asin": "104800001X", "reviewerName": "D. Brennan", "helpful": [0, 1], "reviewText": "I hate it when my shirt collars, not otherwise secured in place by buttons, end up in weird places throughout the day. I purchased some steel collar stays to use with these magnets but they were only vaguely magnetic. I ended up using 2 of these magnets - one in the collar with the stay and the other inside my shirt, to lock my collar in place. They work flawlessly. They are the perfect size, and there are plenty of magnets in case you forget to remove them at the end of the day.", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "Perfect for collar stay management", "unixReviewTime": 1390953600, "reviewTime": "01 29, 2014"}
{"reviewerID": "A3Q5W5E7TDVLJF", "asin": "104800001X", "reviewerName": "funnyc130", "helpful": [0, 0], "reviewText": "These little magnets are really powerful for there size. I am using them to make secret compartments in custom made boxes. Each one hols about .8 of a pound.", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "Neat", "unixReviewTime": 1369958400, "reviewTime": "05 31, 2013"}
```

each file contains several hundreds of thousands of lines like this.

How can I randomly get 1000 of the values of the key `reviewText` from all files altogether?
The final output will be saved in a text file and each line will contain one `reviewText` value.

Here is the source to get such big files containing the amazon reviews:
    http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/

The above sample is from this file:
    http://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon/productGraph/categoryFiles/reviews_Tools_and_Home_Improvement_5.json.gz

Comment: Please post the code you have written until now.

Comment: You will obviously have to read all the files in the setup phase, unless you have some other way to get an approximation of the number of records in each, or you don't care how "random" it is.  Step one, get the sample space. Step two, pick 1000 of them at random (from random import sample)  It is unfortunate that I don't see any unique identifier for each review, so you will probably have to make your own id for each review -- possibly (filename, recordnumber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using python is not a requirement, you can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the json on the commandline and then select 1000 lines randomly from that.

```
jq '.reviewText' reviews*.json | shuf | head -n1000
```